# Is there a way to determine locations inside buildings for android?

Tags: android, gps, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to track position of an Android device in a building?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279946/how-to-track-position-of-an-android-device-in-a-building)

These days I work on a program to locate a user application inside the buildings, I think it can done by GPS .

But I read on the Internet that GPS does not work inside buildings, is there a way to determine the user's location inside the building or user tracking inside the building ?