# Point a computer to an Android phone - position or direction of the phone based on its sensors?

Tags: android, sensor-fusion

I am working on a project that integrates and Android phone and the Kinect sensor.  I would like to point the Kinect (it will be integrated with a device to split around) to the Android phone. For that I need to send the position of the phone in a room (or just the direction) to the computer and then split the kinect. Which is the best way to do that?

I have been doing some tests with the Android sensors, but I dont know if the Android rotation vector should be enough or I also need to combine with data from the magnetometer and the accelerometer. This problem should be easy than indoor positioning because it is in the same room and I just need to know the direction where is the phone located (I don't need the exact location). Any clue or good reference will  help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generally available solution that I am aware of to do this. Having the rotation or the orientation of the device is not sufficient to compute your position within a room (as any free body motion equation will tell you).

You could potentially use the an integration of linear acceleration with some known starting point. But that is fraught with it's own set of [challenges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499959/indoor-positioning-system-based-on-gyroscope-and-accelerometer]). Though in your case it may be enough to get a rough estimate of your position, just so long as you are accurate enough to get the kinect facing in your general direction.