# how to measure rate of rotation using using smartphone sensors

Tags: android, rotation, android-sensors, gyroscope, motion-detection

I am trying to make a game in which the rate a game event occurs (such as climbing or rowing or spinning a wheel) is proportional to the rate at which the user rotates/spins  an android device, using either world coordinates or device coordinates.I would like to use accelerometer and gyroscope(or any sensor present on current generation smartphones)

I have looked at [calculating distances using accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572769/calculating-distances-using-accelerometer) and [Indoor Positioning System based on Gyroscope and Accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499959/indoor-positioning-system-based-on-gyroscope-and-accelerometer) . Apparently accurate position/velocity detection is impossible using only these two sensors due to noise.

So my question is : Is it still possible to measure the rate of spinning or rotating of a current gen smartphone.If so how and which types of rotation can be measured?

I do not care about exact displacement or velocity of the device , just some fairly accurate measurement of rate of some  repetitive motion to drive game events.

Comment: Did you find the answer yet? If yes, It would be helpful if you can share it, as I am looking for the same. Thanks.