# Is it possible to use accelerometer to measure short distances?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement some kind of distance measure in my app. I read through this link: [What is the real world accuracy of phone accelerometers when used for positioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027724/what-is-the-real-world-accuracy-of-phone-accelerometers-when-used-for-positionin) and it turns out that accelerometers were inaccurate.

But that post was answered 5 years ago. So how accurate are phone accelerometers nowadays? You can get distance through double integration which results in drift. But is it possible to compensate for drift through short distances, such as one meter? How accurate would it be tracking movement across such short distances nowadays?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572769/calculating-distances-using-accelerometer

Comment: Well yeah, of course it's a duplicate. But that question was asked 3 years ago as well, I was asking for updated information about accelerometers accuracy. A lot can happen in 3 years when it comes to hardware, that's why I'm asking. Plus I'm asking how noticeable is drift error across short distances.

Comment: My _guess_ (without really knowing anything) is that these sensors are not very much better nowadays. The intended use is measuring which angle the phone is held at, not calculating movement, and if a better accelerometer costs one cent more (or maybe, for a really good one, thousands of dollars?) the manufacturers will save that cent. In contrast to GPS, which has improved, but in that case there is an immediate benefit of better positioning.