# Rough idea of distance IMU has traveled

Tags: ios, accelerometer

I've written an `iOS` app that relies on moving the device throughout physical space. I'm dealing with noise on the `IMU` and for those of you who know much about `accelerometers` you may have heard about the [double integration issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17573500/332578).

If I lay my device on the table it picks up enough noise that it thinks it's moving slowly. I incorporated a "minimum" value and this seems to work but it also means if you move the device very slow you won't pick up the movement.

What is a good way to filter out this unwanted noise? [Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)?

```
float ax = 0, ay = 0, az = 0;
float MIN = 0.002;
int MULT = 5;

...

[self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
     withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData  *data, NSError *error) {
         float x = data.acceleration.x;
         float y = data.acceleration.y;
         float z = data.acceleration.z;

         // find & store difference between last accel amount
         float dx = ax - x;
         float dy = ay - y;
         float dz = az - z;
         float diff = fabsf(dx + dy + dz);

         NSLog(@"%f %f %f", dx, dy, dz);

         if(diff > MIN * MULT) {
             // work some magic
         }

         // save current values for next iteration
         ax = x;
         ay = y;
         az = z;
     }];
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I was having the same problem with my app that records device movement to be played back later and I found a workaround by collecting data every 1/30 seconds and filling in the remaining 50% of my 60fps recording by averaging the two positions. Maybe this could help?

Comment: @Adalex3 Clever solution, thanks for the comment. At some point I started leveraging optical slam which works on pretty much any device with a camera. Cheers!