# Unable to read motion data from ti sensor tag flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using [flutter_blue_plus](https://github.com/boskokg/flutter_blue_plus) example code  to get services provided by [ti sensor tag CC2650](https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/swru410a/swru410a.pdf?ts=1698070121123&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FTIDC-CC2650STK-SENSORTAG). Some of the services working fine, like button push.

But i am not able to get the movement data

[image]

if the sensor is connected to their app it provides the movement data as well.

[image][image]

Comment: What happens if you read the movement data characteristic?

Comment: every time, i subscribe or read the movement data characteristics, It always returns [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. (as highlighted in screenshot.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless-connectivity/bluetooth-group/bluetooth/f/bluetooth-forum/802294/tidc-cc2650stk-sensortag-unable-to-fetch-accelerometer-gyro-data-in-application-from-services-and-characteristics) in the TI Bluetooth Forum the Movement Service need to enable the sensors before reading them:

> The movement service needs to enable the sensors first, this is done through the Movement Configuration characteristic (f000aa82-0451-4000-b000-000000000000).
> **To enable all the sensors for movement write 0xff,0x00 to the config characteristic**. If you want it to sleep when not moved (Wake on Shake) write 0x7F,0x00 instead.

Comment: i have got the values

[130,255,153,0,197,0,121,0,53,0,140,239,99,1,125,1,218,255]

it includes the value of accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer, how i can detect these values. Can you provide help with this as well, Thanks.

Comment: This post suggests that the needed info is no longer available: https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless-connectivity/bluetooth-group/bluetooth/f/bluetooth-forum/786410/cc2650-teardown-full-gatt-table-no-longer-available The one answer contains an excel document that contains a description of the value, but I believe it is not complete, it looks like it contains only gyro and accelerometer

Comment: Deeply thankful for Michael Kotzjan's expert guidance in deciphering sensor data values.

Comment: This is the characteristic data received from invensense MPU-9250 sensor used in sensor tag CC2650 STK.
initial values
[138,255,185,0,164,0,84,2,160,0,108,64,50,2,101,253,28,252]

final values
[120,255,122,0,203,0,152,2,216,0,112,64,27,29,253,44,247]

GXLSB:GXMSB:GYLSB:GYMSB:GZLSB:GZMSB, AXLSB:AXMSB:AYLSB:AYMSB:AZLSB:AZMSB

this how data is arranged.



how can detect the direction of the movement and how much it is moved?

Comment: There are already questions about getting to the distance using an accelerometer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572769/calculating-distances-using-accelerometer If this does not help you feel free to ask a new question :)