# Augmented Reality, Move 3d model respective to device movement

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, augmented-reality

I am working on augmented reality app. I have augmented a 3d model using open GL ES 2.0. Now, my problem is when I move device a 3d model should move according to device movement speed. Just like this app does : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/augment/id506463171?l=en&ls=1&mt=8. I have used UIAccelerometer to achieve this. But, I am not able to do it. 
         Should I use UIAccelerometer to achieve it or any other framework?

Answer (score 2):

It is complicated algorithm rather than just Accelerometer. You'd better use any third party frameworks, such as Vuforia, Metaio. That would save a lot of time.

Download and check a few samples apps. That is exactly what you want.

https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps

You could use Unity3D to load your 3D model and export XCODE project. Or you could use open GL ES.

Comment: I have checked vuforia samples. But, It's not suitable for this.

Comment: I am using Vuforia framework to augment 3d model in native iOS. It's okay. But, I want to move 3d model when I move device. It is not provided in any sample code.

Comment: Could you try to use Unity script to move your model based on your Accelerometer status? http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-acceleration.html and http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Input.html Accelerometer part

Answer (score 1):

From your comment am I to understand that you want to have the model anchored at a real world location? If so, then the easiest way to do it is by giving your model a GPS location and reading the devices' GPS location. There is actually a lot of research going into the subject of positional tracking, but for now GPS is your best (and likely only) option without going into advanced positional tracking solutions.

Seeing as I can't add comments due to my account being too new. I'll also add a warning not to try to position the device using the accelerometer data. You'll get far too much error due to the double integration of acceleration to position (See [Indoor Positioning System based on Gyroscope and Accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499959/indoor-positioning-system-based-on-gyroscope-and-accelerometer)).

Answer (score 0):

- I would definitely use Vuforia for this task.
- Regarding your comment:

  > I am using Vuforia framework to augment 3d model in native iOS. It's okay. But, I want to 
  >   move 3d model when I move device. It is not provided in any sample code.

Well, it's not provided in any sample code, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's impossible or too difficult.

I would do it like this (working on Android, C++, but it must be very similar on iOS anyway):

- locate your renderFrame function
- simply do your translation before actual DrawElements:

  `QCARUtils::translatePoseMatrix(xMOV, yMOV, zMOV, &modelViewProjectionScaled.data[0]);`

  Where the data for the movement would be prepared by a function that reads them from the accelerometer as a time and acceleration...

What I actually find challenging is to find just the right calibration for a proper adjustment of the output from the sensor's API, which is a completely different and AR/Vuforia unrelated question. Here I guess you've got a huge advantage over Android devs regarding various devices...