# Is it possible to draw a line on map in windows phone 8 using accelerometer?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, gps, bing-maps

I want to draw a line on map using accelerometer which tracks location continuously. It should work indoor also where there is no GPS location. Is it possible?

Comment: Accelerometer does not track location.

Comment: i know that accelerometer doesn't track location. i want to draw line on map using it.

Comment: no , use a geoposition sensor instead. It would work

Comment: @Amu : geoposition works only when there is GPS signal. I want it to work if there is no GPS signal in indoor location.

Comment: well points on the maps gets plotted with the help of their geoCoordinate Values, how would you get GeoCoordinates using Accelerometer?

Answer (score 0):

I think the real question here is "Can I draw a line on the map control in wp8?"

Yes you can, here's a great tutorial on the Nokia developer wiki: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/index.php?title=Drawing_shapes_with_Windows_Phone_maps_API&ampdiff=179775&ampoldid=178118

Comment: I know what i've asked. I completed the project which draws a line on the map using GeoCoordinates. But my problem is when there is no GPS working, it should draw a line on the map. So the better option for me is using accelerometer. So if there is no signal, it should skip to accelerometer.

Comment: In that case I'd point you to this stackoverflow post regarding an Android app that wants to track indoor position: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499959/indoor-positioning-system-based-on-gyroscope-and-accelerometer