# Record distance using accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer

Is there any way to find the distance the phone has moved. I don't want to use GPS since I want to detect changes of shorter than 1 meter. Is this possible to do using accelerometer? Is there any example code for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indoor Positioning System based on Gyroscope and Accelerometer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499959/indoor-positioning-system-based-on-gyroscope-and-accelerometer)

Comment: This question has come up soooo many times...