# Use Android Device Sensors To Measure Distance

Tags: java, android, position, android-sensors

I have started programming an Android Application to **Measure short distances (in Meters)** between two points so for example the user hits a start button then the application saves the current Location then while the user is walking the application shows him the distance in **meters** from the starting point.

How to achieve that **considering not to use GPS or Networking** ? I have searched around in Google and SO. I think **Motion Sensors and Accelerometers** are not the way to go but found nothing about Position Sensors like **Orientation Sensor and Geomagnetic Field Sensor**. Can I use Position Sensors to Achieve the case described above?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7500306/3768458

It gives some links on why this is a difficult thing to achieve.

Also there is the method to use the  Gyroscope and Accelerometer with a so called Kalman Filter.

Take alook at this answer for that approach:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13925886/3768458

Comment: Thanks For the reply and as expected accelerometers are useless in my case but what I want is some sort of Coordinates System that uses a benchmark say for exmple North Pole If that is possible then the problem of indoor distance measuring is solved

Answer (score 0):

There are many books about Mobile Sensors in other words Android Augmented Reality.Try this book it helped me download [here](http://freepdf-books.com/pro-android-augmented-reality/)

Comment: Link is not valid anymore!

Comment: @IonutNegru I know it is so late anyway here is the [link](http://freepdf-books.com/pro-android-augmented-reality/)

Comment: Thank you, I confirm that the new link works. You should edit the answer also to include the new link.