# Use mobile to detect where the user is standing in a room

Tags: opencv, ibeacon, virtual-reality

Please inspire me. I am thinking a VR idea that a user can walk around in a virtual world with just a Google Cardboard. It doesn't have to be accurate. It just needs a feeling that when you walk toward a virtual object, the virtual object get closer to use. May you give me any idea and url reference about how to get the user's rough position?

Bonus: there are several people in this room, there are furnitures in this room.

There are some ideas i am thinking about:

1. opencv SLAM, it doesn't need to really map the world perfectly, it just need to use the camera to guess the possible. The problem is, it may get huge influence when other people walk around
2. iBeacon, with 3 iBeacons, it maybe able to get its position by measure the strength go those iBeacon signal. But i also hear that the strength signal could be influenced by a lot of things which makes it extremely irreliable.
3. accelerometer and gyroscope. Well... I actually have no idea how to do that, gyroscope gives me the direction, which is cool, but accelerometer just give me the acceleration. it can't give me the velocity, or can it?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499959/indoor-positioning-system-based-on-gyroscope-and-accelerometer and did you try googling "local positioning system wifi gyro" or sth.?

Comment: If it is not accurate and low latency you will probably make your users motion sick. This is a difficult problem and that's why all current position tracking VR headsets use external tracking systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some inspiration here (not my project): https://www.researchgate.net/publication/290428906_A_Virtual_Reality-based_Multiplayer_Game_using_Fine-grained_Localization

I'd consider using the camera on the phone and markers, like [Arcuo](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26) to make mapping easier (one in each direction for example). This would not cover furniture and other people, though. However, if you network it like in the example above you can use each phones own estimation of its position and broadcast it to the others.