# 2D indoor mapping using motion sensors

Tags: accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope, motion

Is the data from accelerometer and/or gyroscope sufficient enough to construct a path of movement (on a plain canvas)?

The environment is indoors, so usage of GPS data is out of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've though about this topic more than once.
AFAIK, there are some studies showing results using accelerometers/gyros but the calculations are complex, and to be possible it depends on the processing power / memory you have available in your project.
I've then found posts about something called subpos and I see it as an alternative, you can read something here: https://hackaday.io/project/4872-subpos-positioning-system
The basic idea is to have some beacons and then calculate position using wifi signals.
I think that a combination of the two conceps (subpos + sensors) could be useful in a practical approach.

You can found more info in this question: [Indoor Positioning System based on Gyroscope and Accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499959/indoor-positioning-system-based-on-gyroscope-and-accelerometer)